# Custom filtering on subscription in AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, appsync-apollo-client

Is it possible to have custom filtering logic on subscription in AWS AppSync?

As I know, current behavior is:
e.g. my schema is like the following

```
type Mutation {
  createEvent(userId: ID!, event: Event!): Event!
}

type Subscription {
  onEvent(userId: ID!): Event!
  @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createEvent"])
}
```

Current behavior of AppSync is, when I trigger createEvent, AppSync promise that the subscriber of Subscription receive the Event if the userId are equal.
i.e. the filtering logic of AppSync is sth like

```
if (Muatation.userId == Subscription.userId) {
  // forward to subscriber
}
```

But what if I want different filtering logic?
For example, I want to subscribe all other events except those triggered by me?
i.e.

```
if (Muatation.userId != Subscription.userId) {
  // forward to subscriber
}
```

So, is it possible to have custom filtering logic in AppSync?

Answer (score 6):

Currently, this use case is not supported by AppSync.

Adding custom filtering may be considered in the future.

Comment: Has anything changed in this matter in recent years?

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at possible filtering method here - [appsync-doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/aws-appsync-real-time-data.html)

It doesn't seem possible

only thing you can do is, add a small logic in your client to detect if the Subscription is yours by comparing userid's.